# All 3D viewport controls not working

Tags: 3d-view

Was working with Blender tonight and suddenly all 3d view port controls stopped working. Can not Pan, Zoom or Rotate my view port with my mouse. I can not select objects on screen by clicking, only drag select works to select items in the 3D view port. Number pad controls are not working. (Numb Lock is on).

Tried

-Loading another file.

-Restarting Blender

-Rebooting Computer

-Setting Blender Preferences to factory default.

None of these things worked.
Only 3d view port controls that still work are rotate,zoom,move gizmos in the upper right of the view port. (But I don't want to use those.)

This is Blender 3.0

Edit: Also tried upgrading to 3.0.1 and uninstalling and reinstalling Blender. Viewport is still unresponsive as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. There was a setting in Blender that was turned on but not obvious. I never found what the setting was but, deleting the *userpref.blend* file and reopening Blender got my controls to work again.

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The setting that fixed it for me was *Auto Depth* as found [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/365670/discussions/0/1694969361091414347/).

In a nutshell:

1. Go to *Edit > Preferences > Navigation*
2. Make sure *Auto Depth* is checked

I have no idea how it got unchecked in the first place, but everything magically started working as soon as I checked it.